# How to put the heading as the first binding and content below that while heading alone have mark

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
 <li class="checked-list" ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.details">Your details are <strong ng-bind="detail.Id"></strong>.
    <br/>
    <span ng-bind="detail.description"></span>
 </li>
```

**I want it the output like below:**

**X** Your details are **Doctor**

Doctor of 3 states covering north and south of Australia.

**At the moment, it displays like this: (I mean the X is common for both the heading and the content. I want the X to be only on heading line)**

Your details are **Doctor**

**X**

Doctor of 3 states covering north and south of Australia.

Comment: this sounds like  a css problem. I can't even tell where the **X** is generated from what is shown. need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl: This X is not a CSS problem lol, this is being displayed purposefully as a number/bullotbutton type of list, that is all fine, we have a customer directive for that and we use that, but its with the place of display. It dispplays properly when we dont have the nested span, but when we have nested span, it displays common for both the heading and content

Comment: @charlietfl:its after all a small tweaking of the code I have. Just a small syntax change, I dont know how though. I am trying out different options. In lay man terms, if you do not understand, I need a heading and the content underneath that and that is how it displays as per my code, but I want the "X" on heading line rather than being in center (Or common) for both heading and content

Comment: Please provide code about how the `x` is displayed. Without that, I don't think anyone would be able to help out here

Comment: You want angular1.x or angular2 code?

Comment: @ti2005: Anything would help. I am not sure if you can do both ;-) Can you do 1.x?

Comment: @nikjohn: It has got nothing to do with the class of X as it is from UL I specified. I want a simple thing man, heading with X. Can you do that or not. I explained many times what I want and even displayed the sample expectedoutput

Comment: @Learner What actually you want? Because there is no much difference between 1.x and 2. So you don't bother about that. ;-)

Comment: @Learner Show some respect to others.

Comment: @ti2005: I am confuse

Answer (score 0):

I have kept X as default bullet option , If you want you can change it to number or other item style using css

https://plnkr.co/edit/2MXhucXw0bjWUJ1UfOSb?p=preview

```
<ul>
    <li class="checked-list" ng-repeat="detail in ctrl">
      Your details are                     
        <strong ng-bind="detail.Id"></strong>                                                    <br />
        <span ng-bind="detail.description">
        </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Check the plunkr for answer

Comment: Thank you very much